# M2: How to add store address to transactional email / invoice email?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, invoice, order-email, transactional-mail

In M1, our invoice email templates contained the store address:

```
{{config path='general/store_information/address'}}
```

In M2, this does not work, because store information / address is split into multiple fields.

Is there an easy way how to insert the store address into transactional emails? Best with only one variable instead of an entire variables section? I would prefer a one-fits-all approach; one email template for all countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from Magento development docs

> The selection of available variables depends on which template you use as a basis. The template-specific variables are contained in a comment at the top of each template on the file system. (For example, look at app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/email/account_new.html.

You can read more https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

So you can rewrite  `<Magento_Email_module_dir>/view/frontend/email/footer.html and add your variable.`

I found that you can also add customer variables in backend.
System>Custom Variables:

And one more information:
I found on Marketing => email templates=> and load Footer (Magento/luma)
and this template load address using:

```
<p class="address"> {{var store.getFormattedAddress()|raw}}  </p>
```

**Uptate: for Magento 2.3.4:**

```
<p class="address"> {{var store.formatted_address|raw}} </p>
```

Ref:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Email/email/footer.html

Migrating templates:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html

Or just switch to use legacy template in mail template table.

Comment: This does not print state/region.

Comment: Please check update

Comment: Thank you @BartZalas. I used <p class="address"> {{var store.getFormattedAddress()|raw}}  </p> but it displays full region and not the region code. So I changed in renderer.php.

Comment: If I use {{var store.getFormattedAddress()|raw}} and load the template in admin >> Marketing >>  Email Templates, and set the same template in Content>> Configuration>>Transactional Emails >> Footer Template, the address is not printed. @BartZalas could you please help? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/322294/magento-2-issue-with-email-template-loaded-in-admin-marketing-email-templates

Comment: Please read my update from yesterday, there is not get

Answer (score 1):

```
{{config path="general/store_information/street_line1"}} // Street Address

{{config path="general/store_information/street_line2"}} // Street Address Line 2
```