# Magento 2 Issue with email template loaded in admin Marketing >> Email templates

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, footer

I have added custom code in footer.html for email footer.
{{var store.getFormattedAddress()|raw}} is being used to display the store address.

If I load the footer template in Marketing >> Email templates, and assign the same in Content >> Configuration >> Transactional emails >> Footer Template, store address is not displayed in footer.

But that is not the case if defaut footer is set in Content >> Configuration >> Transactional emails >> Footer Template.

What could be the reason?

**UPDATE**
I removed custom code from footer and added back default code with {{var store.getFormattedAddress()|raw}} in it.
The issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento above 2.3.x:

{{var store.formatted_address|raw}}

So there is no "get"

Ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Email/email/footer.html

Migrating templates:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html

Or just switch to use legacy template in mail template table in database. Just change legacy value to 1 and you can change template to use "get" method.

Comment: Tried it. Same issue.